# Empty Socket InputStream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I'm trying to build a simple web server in Java as practice but I'm running into a very strange issue. When I attempt to read the `InputStream` from the `Socket`, sometimes there is no data to be read.
The process I'm following is this:

I create a `ServerSocket`, listening on port 80, and call `accept()` to get a `Socket`. I then send a request from my browser (Firefox) to `localhost`, which triggers the `accept()` to return the `Socket`.

Sometimes, it will read the HTTP request perfectly. Other times, it fails to read any data (`read()` returns a -1).

Here is some sample code to illustrate what I'm doing, without any exception handling thrown in:

```
ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(80);

while (true)
{
  Socket con = ServerSocket.accept();

  InputStream input = con.getInputStream();

  bytes[] bytes = new bytes[4000000]; // for simplicity, I figured I'd 
                                      // just make the array huge for now

  int bytesRead = input.read(bytes);
  if (bytesRead > 0)
  {
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(bytesRead);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
    {
      sBuffer.append((char) bytes[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(sBuffer.toString());
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I've also tried using a `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedReader` to not avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One socket can receive more packets. So you should create a new thread for every socket. Something like:

```
while(true){
    Socket socket = serv.accept();
    Client client = new Client(socket);
    new Thread(client).start();
}
```

Then you need to create the Client class which implements the runable interface.

```
Socket socket;
public Client(Socket socket){
    this.socket = socket;
}
public void run(){
    while(socket.isConnected()){
        //here reads the packets from the inputstream
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Moving the socket processing into a separate thread solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

You should *always* loop when reading data from an InputStream.  there is no guarantee that all the data will be returned from a single `read()` call (loop until you receive `-1`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It wasn't causing my issue, but its definitely good to know